# Format message in invalid Hibernate data validation

Tags: hibernate, message, validation

I want know If I could format with my personal error message on Date format error in Hibernate Validator.

I have my class attribute look like this.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mm")
private Date hourOpen;
```

Default Error and message in form:error spring tag.

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property hourOpen; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date for value 11; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse 11
```

I want to show "Date format error" message in form:error spring tag.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Key to get default message is: {typeMismatch.yourResultObject.objectAttribute}.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Where do you put this key?

Comment: In lang-xx.properties.

Comment: @Paul  in messages.properties file add typeMismatch.student.dateOfBirth = Date of Birth:Illegal date format!